# How to move the /var/www directory to a USB HDD?

Tags: mount, security, webserver, directory-structure, openbsd

I have a default OpenBSD 5.1 install. How Can I enabled httpd, OK.

QUESTION: How can I use the

```
/dev/sd0a on /mnt/usbhdd type ffs (local, nodev)
```

instead of the default "/var/www" directory? What are the most secure mount options (for a webservers that only servers static html/files)?

Comment: Either mount `/dev/sd0a` to `/var/www` or configure your web server to use `/mnt/usbhdd` instead of `/var/www`.

Comment: "mount /dev/sd0a to /var/www" - :D thanks, afaik this will be the thing :) .. but if I do this, no other things needed?? only mount to /var/www and use it with good user/group? nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Either mount /dev/sd0a to /var/www or configure your web server to use
>   /mnt/usbhdd instead of /var/www. – Marco Oct 29 '12 at 11:41